# Cakephp 3 Automatically set values to a user defined form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am able add/edit/delete with a form created using Cakephp FormHelper.

But I want to use **my own form**  **without html helper**. And it is a big form. In edit, I set an entity to view. I gave names to elements same as column names.

But the values are not set.

**The view is in a plugin.**

Can anybody please tell me how to automatically set values in a user-defined form.

I have created a form tag in the form as follows, hoping that "context" will be set and values will appear

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create( $company ); ?>
```

and also end , end of the form.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

In between the form tags there are many html form elements.
I am posting one of them for which i have set the name same as column name

```
      <div class="form-group panel">
        <h6 for="pt-name">Former Name1</h6>
        <input type="text" name="company_former_name_one" placeholder="Former Name 1" class="form-control">
      </div>
```

My Controller Code :

```
public function profile( $id = null )
{
    $company = $this->Companies->get( $id );

    if ($this->request->is(['post','put']))
    {
        $post = $this->Companies->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data);

        // $post->modified = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if( $this->Companies->save($post) )
        {
        }
    }
    $this->set('company', $company);
}
```

Comment: @AD7six I believe he is trying to create a form which is already filled in with the `Company` entity data on page load, so that you can then edit the entity via the form.

Comment: @AD7six Yes, I am not using form helpers to create the form, as the form is already available and i cannot put the form helpers now, given the time line. If i put <?php echo $company->company_former_name_one ?> inside value, i get the value. But even that is a lot of work. I was wondering if there is any default way to set form "context" when not using form helpers.

Comment: No, you must use the FormHelper if you want it to correctly produce the inputs for you and allow Cake to automatically help you. Otherwise, you need to manually code the inputs yourself so that they contain the correct `name` attributes and preset the value in the same way that the form helper would normally do. Without the helper, you are just building a normal HTML form like any other - it won't do anything special for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CakePHP is not magic

> i cannot put the form helpers now, given the time line

The *simplest* and *fastest* way to do what you're asking is to use helpers.

> I was wondering if there is any default way to set form "context" when not using form helpers

No.

For that to work would require the framework to parse the static html from the template, figure out which bits are supposed to be dynamic, apply some magic/assumptions and then dump the html. CakePHP does not work in this way.

### Use helpers

Instead of static html, use appropriate helper methods. For example [FormHelper::text](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-text-inputs)

```
<div class="form-group panel">
    <h6 for="pt-name">Former Name1</h6>
    <?= $this->Form->text('former_name1') ?>
</div>
```

Which will generate something like:

```
<div class="form-group panel">
    <h6 for="pt-name">Former Name1</h6>
    <input name="former_name1" value="default" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: @ AD7six Got the message loud and clear. Actually I have taken a liking to Cakephp, and probably was expecting magic :)

Comment: @ AD7six and anyone reading this, CakePhp is magic, I am into cakephp for about 10 days, but i tell you it is magic !

Comment: @BhargavS sounds like you've made some progress :)